# Updating a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been stuck on this question for quite sometime and just can't figure it out. I just want to be able to understand what I'm missing and why it's needed.
What I need to do is make a function which adds each given key/value pair to the dictionary. The argument key_value_pairs will be a list of tuples in the form (key, value).

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):

    newinputs = [] #creates new list
    for key, value in key_value_pairs:
        d[key] = value #updates element of key with value
        if key in key_value_pairs:
            newinputs.append((d[key], value)) #adds d[key and value to list
    return newinputs
```

I can't figure out how to update the "value" variable when d and key_value_pairs have different keys.

The first three of these scenarios work but the rest fail

```
>>> d = {}
>>> add_to_dict(d, [])
[]
>>> d
{}

>>> d = {}
>>> add_to_dict(d, [('a', 2])
[]
>>> d
{'a': 2}

>>> d = {'b': 4}
>>> add_to_dict(d, [('a', 2)])
[]
>>> d
{'a':2, 'b':4}

>>> d = {'a': 0}
>>> add_to_dict(d, [('a', 2)])
[('a', 0)]
>>> d
{'a':2}

>>> d = {'a', 0, 'b': 1}
>>> add_to_dict(d, [('a', 2), ('b': 4)])
[('a', 2), ('b': 1)]
>>> d
{'a': 2, 'b': 4}

>>> d = {'a': 0}
>>> add_to_dict(d, [('a', 1), ('a': 2)])
[('a', 0), ('a':1)]
>>> d
{'a': 2}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `dict.update`?

Comment: Sorry, are those outputs what you're getting, or what you want?

Comment: Can you show the output you get vs the output you expect in each case?

Comment: `key in key_value_pairs` will usually be false, because `key_value_pairs` is a list of tuples, but in most cases `key` is not a tuple

Comment: I can't use built in functions such as dict.update. I have to use loops and if statements

Comment: @KanadeSwag: But you just used `list.append`, which is a built in function

Comment: Your question is not clear for me (and for other people too I guess as every answer is different) Do you consider your first example with add_to_dict(d, [('a', 2)]) as invalid ? Would you expect 
{'a':2, 'a': 0} ?

Comment: Why exactly do they fail? The function updates the dictionary to the last value that was inputed onto it. In the scenarios they seem to work... What is the expected output?

Answer (score 51):

Python has this feature built-in:

```
>>> d = {'b': 4}
>>> d.update({'a': 2})
>>> d
{'a': 2, 'b': 4}
```

Or given you're not allowed to use `dict.update`:

```
>>> d = dict(d.items() + {'a': 2}.items())   # doesn't work in python 3
```

Comment: I have to achieve this by only using loops and statements

Comment: @KanadeSwag: This is "only a statement". Those rules are meaningless, as they allow all python code

Comment: I meant if statements, sorry

Comment: @KanadeSwag: That's also a false set of rules, as you also need assignment, key access, arithmetic. Which builtin functions are you allowed to use, and which are you not?

Comment: Notes about `dict.update()`: **(1)** It changes the existing `dict`, **(2)** It returns None, and **(3)** It overwrites existing items (as does the dictionary merge operator `dict1 | dict2`).

Answer (score 24):

With [python 3.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-390/) you can use an `|=` [update operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/):

```
>>> d = {'b': 4}
>>> d |= {'a': 2}
>>> d
{'a': 2, 'b': 4}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a more elegant solution, compared to Eric's 2nd snippet

```
>>> a = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
>>> b = {'a' : 2, 'c' : 3}
>>> c = dict(a, **b)
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> b
{'a': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> c
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

It works both in Python 2 and 3

And of course, the update method

```
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> b
{'a': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> a.update(b)
>>> a
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

However, be careful with the latter, as might cause you issues in case of misuse like here

```
>>> a = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
>>> b = {'a' : 2, 'c' : 3}
>>> c = a
>>> c.update(b)
>>> a
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> b
{'a': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> c
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 10):

The new version of Python3.9 introduces two new operators for dictionaries: union (|) and in-place union (|=). You can use | to merge two dictionaries, while |= will update a dictionary in place. Let's consider 2 dictionaries *d1* and *d2*

```
d1 = {"name": "Arun", "height": 170}
d2 = {"age": 21, "height": 170}
```

```
d3 = d1 | d2 # d3 is the union of d1 and d2
print(d3)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Arun', 'height': 170, 'age': 21}
```

Update d1 with d2

```
d1 |= d2
print(d1)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Arun', 'height': 170, 'age': 21}
```

You can update d1 with a new key weight as

```
d1 |= {"weight": 80}
print(d1)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Arun', 'height': 170, 'age': 21, 'weight': 80}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this post explains it well:
[Dictionary Merge and Update Operators in Python 3.9:](https://blog.teclado.com/python-dictionary-merge-update-operators/)

## Here a summary:

### The Dictionary Update Operator

Dictionary x is being updated by the dictionary y

```
x.update(y)
print(x)
```

### The Dictionary Merge Operator:

Fuse them into a new one. Having:

```
x = {"key1": "value1 from x", "key2": "value2 from x"}
y = {"key2": "value2 from y", "key3": "value3 from y"}
```

**Old way:**

```
z = {**x, **y}
print(z)
```

**New way:**

```
z = x | y
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each key in a python `dict` corresponds to exactly one value. The cases where `d` and `key_value_pairs` have different keys are not the same elements.

Is `newinputs` supposed to contain the key/value pairs that were previously not present in `d`? If so:

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):
  newinputs = []
  for key, value in key_value_pairs:
    if key not in d:
      newinputs.append((key, value))
    d[key] = value
  return newinputs
```

Is `newinputs` supposed to contain the key/value pairs where the key *was* present in `d` and then changed? If so:

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):
  newinputs = []
  for key, value in key_value_pairs:
    if key in d:
      newinputs.append((key, value))
    d[key] = value
  return newinputs
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to return a list of of tuples with (key, old_value) for the keys that were replaced.

You have to save the old value before you replace it:

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):

    newinputs = [] #creates new list
    for key, value in key_value_pairs:
        if key in d:
            newinputs.append((key, d[key]))
        d[key] = value #updates element of key with value
    return newinputs
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to add the keys that do not exist in the dictionary. Here is the code:

```
def add_to_dict(d, key_value_pairs):
    newinputs = [];
    for key, value in key_value_pairs:
        if key not in d.keys():
            d[key] = value
            newinputs.append((key, value));
    return newinputs
```

For each key in new key,value pairs list you have to check if the key is new to the dictionary and add it only then.
Hope it helps ;)