# Syntax error during updating value of dictionary with the text

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I get the invalid syntax error:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the argument have to be a dictionary for the update method? So you would be doing x.update({y:z}) instead of x.update(y:z) which is what you have in the code.

Comment: As mentioned by @RichardKYu, u will need to pass dict to ```update``` function not just key https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694826/updating-a-dictionary-in-python/29695016#29695016

Comment: Welcome! Please [do not post code, errors and logs as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), but copy the relevant parts into the question instead, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update

## update() Parameters

The update() method takes either a dictionary or an iterable object of key/value pairs (generally tuples).

If update() is called without passing parameters, the dictionary remains unchanged.