# Explicit lookup delegation for Python dict instances?

Tags: javascript, python, prototype

So in Javascript, I can set one object to be the **proto** of another. Meaning if lookups fail in the first object, it will delegate to its **proto**. E.g

```js
var baz = {foo: 'bar'}
var buzz = {fizz: 'soup'}

baz.__proto__ = buzz

baz.fizz // 'soup'
```

Is this possible in Python? Say, hypothetically:

```py
baz = {"foo": "bar"}
buzz = {"fizz": "soup"}

# What should this line be?
baz.__proto__ = buzz

baz['fizz'] # "soup"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694826/updating-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: @sushanth nope, has nothing to do with delegation

Comment: Why not, ``baz.update(buzz)`` then ``baz['fizz']`` would result in the expected behaviour.

Comment: @sushanth update will clobber, not delegate