# How to add key value pair to dictionary which is present inside list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
dict_example = {
        "abc": [
            {
                "name": "bcd",
                "gender": "male",
                "options": {
                    "emp_id": "a10734",
                    "address": "cfg",
                    "dept": "IT",
                },
            }
        ]
}
```

I have above dictionary and I need to add below values to options programmatically.

```
"desgn":"Engineer",
"project" : "xyz",
```

I need output in the below formart

```
dict_example = {
        "abc": [
            {
                "name": "bcd",
                "gender": "male",
                "options": {
                    "emp_id": "a10734",
                    "address": "cfg",
                    "dept": "IT",
                    "desgn":"Engineer",
                    "project" : "xyz",
                },
            }
        ]
}
```

Can anyone help me with the above problem it will be great!

Comment: use `dict.update`,  here is example `dict_example['abc'][0]['options'].update({"desgn":"Engineer",
"project" : "xyz",})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694826/updating-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the keys and indices to reach the item and add or change it:

```
dict_example['abc'][0]['options']['design'] = 'Engineer'
dict_example['abc'][0]['options']['project'] = 'xyz'
print(dict_example)
```

The output will be:

```
{'abc': [{'name': 'bcd', 'gender': 'male', 'options': {'emp_id': 'a10734', 'address': 'cfg', 'dept': 'IT', 'design': 'Engineer', 'project': 'xyz'}}]}
```